# How to set a sub-path and CDN for assets simultaneously in vue-cli 3.3+?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

My team's working on a vue project which will use sub-path. Our domain is `https://a.exampl.com`, we are using this project with `https://a.example.com/b`. Now, we want to upload assets to cloud after webpack building and change assets to CDN's link which is different from sub-path, such as `https://cdn.example.com`. My `vue.config.js` like following:

```js
// vue.config.js
const vueConfig = {
  publicPath: './b',
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: []
  }
}
```

Versions:

- `vue-cli`: `4.4.6`
- `Webpack`: `4.44.1`

So how can I modify the `vue.config.js` settings to implement that the project could use `https://a.example.com/b` and assets could use the cdn like `https://cdn.example.com`?

Comment: Hello ! I know this is a bit old but, did you manage to complete this configuration ? I'm currently in this exact same context. Main lead for now would be post-processing base URLs for assets, but a cleaner solution would be preferable. Hope to hear some news here :) Thanks !